# Approximating effective interest rate on a bond

Tags: approximation, finance, actuarial-science

If you have a bond with the following properties:

1. Issued at price $X$;
2. Redeemed at price $Y$;
3. Has a coupon rate of $p$ ;
4. Has a term of $n$ years;

then I am told, in my accounting studies, that the effective interest rate, $r$, can be approximated as

$r\approx(\frac{Y}{X})^\frac{1}{n}-1+p$.

It seems to do a decent job, but I cannot figure out for the life of me why this should work as an approximation.

In attempting to figure this out, I have got to the point of seeing that

$X((1+r)^n+p(\frac{1-(1+r)^n}{r}))=Y$,

but I am unable to use this to get to the above approximation for $r$.

I would really appreciate if someone could help out, as, although the derivation is not directly relevant to my accounting studies, it has been bugging me for some time!

Comment: The bonds I'm familiar with pay a coupon based on the maturity value, not the purchase price, so I don't agree with your equation.

Comment: @saulspatz I should have added that the issue price, $X$, is actually also the nominal value of the bond. The bond is then redeemable at a premium. Hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: Okay, so we might be looking at the effective rate if the bond is called early, where $Y$ is the call price, and the bond is purchased at par.   That makes sense.  Are you looking for an intuitive explanation of the approximation or an analytic justification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{enclose}$
I'll use $i$ for the interest rate, and $v=\frac1{1+i}$.
We have
$$
X=pXa_\enclose{actuarial}{n}+Yv^n\\
X(1-pXa_\enclose{actuarial}{n})=Yv^n\\
X((1+i)^n-ps_\enclose{actuarial}{n})=Y\\
\frac YX=(1+i)^n-ps_\enclose{actuarial}{n}\\
\left(\frac YX\right)^{1/n}=\left((1+i)^n-ps_\enclose{actuarial}{n}\right)^{1/n}
$$
First the intuitive explanation.  The left hand side show that $i$ is the rate of interest we'd have to earn if we put the bond proceeds into a trust fund, out which we paid the coupons, and eventually redeemed the bonds.  Each year, we pay out $pX$ and if $x$ and $Y$ are not very different, as is usual, we earn about $iX$.  That explains the result on an intuitive level.

For a more analytic approach, note that $$\left((1+i)^n-ps_\enclose{actuarial}{n}\right)^{1/n}=(1+i)\left(1-pa_\enclose{actuarial}{n}\right)^{1/n}$$  and
$$pa_\enclose{actuarial}{n}=p\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}i=p\frac{1-(1-ni+o(i))}i\approx np$$ so that $$\left(1-pa_\enclose{actuarial}{n}\right)^{1/n}\approx(1-np)^{1/n}\approx1-p$$

This gives $$\left(\frac YX\right)^{1/n}\approx(1+i)(1-p)=1+i+p-ip\approx1+i-p$$

Basically, this computation just assumes that all second-degree and higher terms, like $i^2$, $p^2$ and $ip$ are negligible, which is reasonable for typical interest rates.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was trying to do something similar ignoring the higher power terms but I couldn't get there - that's really helpful with both the analytic and intuitive explanations!